# Does Yogacara and its Alayavijnana fail compared to a Permanent Self?

Tags: anatman, self, yogacara

So I've been Reading a bit of the Buddhist's boogeyman Shankara and I admit I am maybe biased in writing this(I am open to any refutation of my view,but I have not seen any adequate logical refutation of such),but I'd like to see a buddhist refutation or answer of this following viewpoint of mine based on a reading of Shankara's writings:

the temporary momentary alaya vijnana in yogachara buddhism is the substratum of momentary impressions,desires and ideas wich give rise to the false perception of external objects in their system.ideas and impressions(vasana samskaras)give rise to the appearance of external objects,wich give rise to further ideas and impressions wich give rise to further objects of external perception.however how can this not be a infinite regress(the appearance of external objects give rise to impressions,impressions give rise to the appearance external objects)?if external objects' (even just initial in some starting point in the past,wich buddhism denies due to its adherance to pratityasamutpada)existance is altogether denied to possibly exist rather than the mere appearance of them,how can impressions and desires come about for such objects ''appearance''?

and if there is no permanent substratum to the mind wherein impressions and desires can leave a mark or effect,how can anything be cognized externally(i.e how can vasana samskaras be configured or accumulated(with out wich it cant exist)without a permanent substratum?

such latent impressions cannot exist in a fresh new substratum (i.e person )each moment,because neither desire would arise from the appearance of external objects nor the appearance of external objects from impressions' desire(and the Yogacarin must admit a certain illogical infinite regress even in the case of a assumed permanent substratum)?

a new subtratum cannot have any impressions nor appearance of external objects to give impressions because the substratum,in this case the Alaya vijnana has no connection with its 'causal' substratum due to kshanabhanga.
if there were no permanent substratum there would literally be no experience or consciousness it seems based on the above.

only if a permanent substratum exists can such infinite regress of impression arising the appearance of external objects and vice versa even have any meaning(and even that is illogical as actual regressive infinites do not exist logically but I know that buddhism believes in infinite regression so I'm Granting you this.but such infinite regress would only 'make sence'within a permanent substratum).

I don't See how the Buddhist Doctrine of alayavijnana does not fail,and how only a permanent self can explain the infinite regress of ideas leading to (the appearance of) external objects and vice versa(wich itself is illogical in my opinion,but I am granting you guys' this for the sake of argument only).

if Kshanabhanga(wich is a Buddhist Tenet fundamental to buddhism) is Denied here,as some may Wish to do,and the substratums have a causal chain wich must be substantial;then how is this not a Permanent Self of the tirthikas for all intents and purposes?

buddhism denies this,and all of buddhism except Jonang would all fail if this were admitted,but if this were the case we have a permanent cognizing substantial 'self'/'person' through all the 3 times.

I don't see how the momentary alayavijnana is not a failure.

Answer (score 3):

Shankara is Advaita Vedanta, a branch of Hindu philosophy inspired by Buddhism, so why are we talking about him? I guess you were reading his critics of Buddhism and this is what you ask?

Your confusion about "infinite regress" comes from your materialistic assumption that separate objects exist in and of themselves, without observers. But in reality, separation into objects is a feature of the observing mind.

The observing mind does not arise all at once but emerges gradually from impressions of interactions. These impressions and interactions are automatic and undifferentiated, they have to accumulate until the patterns in them become obvious enough so that individual objects can be delineated. The mind is nothing other than the sum total of these accumulated impressions giving rise to an ability to recognize.

It's not that nothing exists prior to the delineation, but whatever does exist is not delineated, so before delineation there are no separate objects to talk about. The boundaries between objects are arbitrary and are drawn by the observing mind. Different beings delineate different objects thereby creating their specific subjective realms. The desires beings have are for those subjectively delineated objects.

What you call substratum is nothing other than the cyclicaly dying and reemerging medium of living beings. They are the carriers or the bearers of the samsaric mind. This mind is partially taught to and partially reinvented by every newly born baby. No permanent self is necessary because beings take turns carrying the torch of the samsaric mind and passing it on down the line.

Alayavijnana is the sum total of information carrying forward by the diversity of media that the samsaric mind can draw upon as it recreates itself in the new generations of sentient beings.

Comment: this fails to adress any of my points.

Comment: I made clear that I am talking about the appearance of objects,not objects themselves in OP,and infinite regress still applies to the fact that without samskaras,the rupabhedam of external object cannot come into being and vice versa,so we have a chicken and an egg problem,unless sometime in the infinite past there actually was a external object to give rise to the first samskara and then rupa-bhedams starting the process,but this is anathema to buddhism because of paticasamupada as all outlined in the OP.there was no starting point where original impressions could be made from actual objects.

Comment: As I explained, it's not the objects that give rise to samskaras but the undifferentiated interaction. Objects only exist as appearances. Outside of appearance there are no objects, only the undifferentiated "stuff". This is why Yogacara is dubbed the Representation-Only teaching.

Comment: that doesn't refute anything I've said.its the APPEARANCE of objects that give rise to samskaras,wich is what I said in OP.you are attacking a strawman.

Comment: No, no - appearances of objects EMERGE from Samskaras, not the other way around.

Comment: and further samskaras emerge from the appearances of objects.samskaras enable appearances and vice versa.

Comment: samskaras and appearances are in a infinite regressive cycle.there needs to be explained them how samskaras arise and from what if appearances do not give rise to samskaras(wich is basic yogacara,but you are denying it to save your metaphysics)

Comment: So, here's the way it works (you asked a question to get an answer, didn't you, not just to asert your position, I hope?): Imprints of interactions are samskaras. As they accumulate they grow into ability to delineate objects and recognize them. The appearance of these subjectively delineated objects feed back into the process of interaction, thereby stimulating and conditioning formation of new samskaras and maintenance of existing samskaras. So the process is not truly an infinite loop, more like an iterative progression with feedback.

Comment: that doesn't answer from where the first samskara arises.

Comment: The first samskaras arise from accumulation or memorizing of patterns of similar interactions in series of random interactions. Please reread my answer and all comments. You keep thinking that object is something external. Instead, information about similarities accumulates until it becomes memory, recognition, delineation of object, and finally subjective experience. First information accumulates on the basis of random interactions, which despite being random and undelineated nevertheless discover some regularity or patterns.

Comment: so this still doesnt answer my question.how were initial interactions possible if actual objects dont exist?how did the first appearances of objects arise?

Comment: Interactions were analog, not discrete, unseparated, like the turbulence in air or in water. Some of these turbulence-like interactions had feedback cycles so they effectively fed and supported their own continuation. As they continued, they accumulated information about past interactions. This information eventually supported emergence of semiosis, the ability to recognize an upcoming interaction by its characteristic signs. These recognitions is what we now know as appearances of objects.

Comment: @johnyman in my opinion you are correct the process is infinite. But that is not a problem. I think in Buddhism infinite past is accepted. This process has been going on from infinite past.

Comment: @johnyman your question is wrong in so kany levels. First it assumes the infinite regress is a flaw then it assumes the Vedantic sepf can store information, which is wrong, according Advaita the self is nirguna, it can't store any info. So both Advaita Vedantins and Buddhists agree on this.

Comment: @AndreiVolkov it seems that you are making your own theories as to how Alyavijana and Samkaras came about rather than sticking with tradition. Samkaras and Alayavijanana are interdependent and if I understand correctly Samkaras can only be caused by Alayavijnana, not by some random interactions. These so called random io interactions also have minimal basic Alayavijanana, which you are missing to understand.